# Import unmanaged code import to delphi from C#

Tags: c#, delphi, marshalling, unmanaged, dllimport

I have a c# class that connects to the dll that works good.

Now I need the same functions in Delphi. what is the best way to do it? I don't want to write all the imports again in Delphi. is there a way to import the c# class in delphi or any other way of doing that quick and easy..

This is one function in my c# class:

```
    /// Return Type: ABS_STATUS->ABS_LONG->int
    ///pszDsn: ABS_CHAR*
    ///phConnection: ABS_CONNECTION*
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("bsapi.dll", EntryPoint = "ABSOpen", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern int ABSOpen([System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute()] [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string pszDsn, ref uint phConnection);
```

Comment: Native Delphi, or Delphi for .NET?

Comment: Yes it's not a .net dll, I think its C++. how wold I import it directly in Delphi, I need to rewrite all the medhods and functions in delphi code??

Comment: @Jim Mischel i'm using Native Delphi version 5

Comment: Yes you must write manually the imports unless it is an activex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simple in Delphi:

```
function ABSOpen(pszDsn: PAnsiChar; var phConnection: Cardinal): Integer; 
    stdcall; external 'bsapi.dll';
```

You'll no doubt have more functions than this, but they should all be easy enough. If I were you I would go back to the original C++ header file which should be much easier to translate than your p/invokes.

I don't think there is any good conversion tool for p/invoke to Delphi import unit. Even for C++ header to Delphi, I'm not convinced that there is good universal tool. You can look at the [JEDI project which has some useful resources](http://jedi.grizzlydev.com/www/api-howto.html), but in my view it's time to roll up your sleeves!

Comment: I have the header file, there is some tool that would do some of the conversion for me?

Comment: I added a link to the JEDI project, which has excellent resources and some tools, but I still think you'll be better doing it manually. The job will be done better that way.

Comment: Thank you very much. one thing only.. what is IntPtr in delphi?

Comment: It depends. That's why you need to go back to the header file because you often would translate differently to delphi than for a pinvoke

Comment: Read the dr bob article that is linked from the jedi page. Also, how many functions do you need to call?

Comment: Not worth trying to use a tool for 5 imports. I've done one for you already!

Comment: I don't know why but delphi doesn't like it. the error is: Field definition not allowed after methods or properties

Comment: That's because you are putting the code in my answer inside a class. Don't do that. This is not C# or Java where all methods have to live in classes. Make it a standalone function.

Comment: The pointers I don't know how to convert. (I added one function that uses it).

Comment: This is a new question. I answered your first question.

Comment: You'll need to include struct definitions in the question

Comment: Ok I'll do that in the other question